# Is multiple storyboards the only way to make my graphics-heavy app look good across all iPhones?

Tags: ios, autolayout

My app has a lot of image assets so adjustments I make (resizing and changing position on the screen) to my artboards that make it look good in iPhone X make it look awful in iPhone 5 or 6 or XR. The main problem seems to be reconciling different screen dimensions, rather than sizes. Is there another way besides doing a whole new storyboard for the taller X screen dimension?

We have tried auto layout but that only works for the UI elements, not image-only graphics. What we end up with is a compromise that doesn't look fantastic on either screen.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, try making more specific questions, this one is surely too broad to be here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you can do that through Auto Layout. There are so many techniques, you can use multipliers, you can resize heights based on widths, you can make views have a percentage size of other views, possibilities are endless. You can even make custom constraints for a specific model.

You should study more about Auto Layout, it is possible to make them all look exactly like you want.

Comment: I did screenshots of each screen in iPhone 5S, 6, X, XR and the differences was vast. In some screens UI elements weren't even visible. Do I need to do artboards for each device as well?

Comment: The differences are vast because you're not using Auto Layout correctly, no, usually you just need one, you need to apply multipliers.